# How to avoid .subscribe in subscribe in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, subscribe, flatmap

I have a code snippet using Rxjava and I have written it using subscribing inside a subscription. How can I use the only one subscribe using maps or flatmaps?

```
amount.textChanges.observable.map {
        when {
            (it.isNotEmpty() && it.toBigDecimal() > BigDecimal(1500)) -> showDialog(R.string.max_amount_error)
            (it.isNotEmpty() && it.toBigDecimal() > BigDecimal.ZERO) -> {
                getCommissionUseCase.execute(it.toInt() * 100).subscribe { payment ->
                    commission.accept((payment.data.toDouble() / 100).toString())
                }.untilDestroy()
            }
            (it.isEmpty()) -> nextBtnEnabled.consumer.accept(false)
        }
    }.subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

```kotlin
amount.textChanges.observable
  .flatMapCompletable {
    when {
      (it.isNotEmpty() && it.toBigDecimal() > BigDecimal(1500)) -> Completable.fromAction { showDialog(R.string.max_amount_error) }
      (it.isNotEmpty() && it.toBigDecimal() > BigDecimal.ZERO) -> getCommissionUseCase.execute(it.toInt() * 100)
         .doOnSuccess { payment ->
           commission.accept((payment.data.toDouble() / 100).toString())
         }
         .ignoreElement()
      (it.isEmpty()) -> Completable.fromAction { nextBtnEnabled.consumer.accept(false) }
    }
  }.subscribe()
```

You can use `doOnNext`, `ignoreElements` if you're using `Observable` instead of the `doOnSuccess`, `ignoreElement`, which is only available on `Single`